# initializing parameter in Cplex concert technology C++

Tags: c++, cplex

In my problem, N  = set of nodes, s  Є N  =  index used for  sources, d  Є N  =  index used for  destinations. 
Zsd  = 1 , if the path between (s )and (d ) is disrupted. The problem has to be iterated  (w)  times. I have to initialize one notation in Cplex C++ concert technology. The notation is
Zw = {(s,d) Є  NXN|Zsdw  = 1}: indices for disrupted flows in at iteration (w).
I am not able to initialize for (Zw).  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you better describe your problem? I mean, are you having problems with declaring variables z or whatelse? The title says "parameter" but the text seems to be about something else

Comment: Actually, I am using bender's decomposition to solve the problem. (Zsd ) are binary variables of subproblem which will become an input to the master problem as  Zw = {(s,d) Є NXN|Zsdw = 1}: indices for disrupted flows in at iteration (w). It consider the indices of only those  (Zsd ) where value is true.

Comment: Still utterly unclear where your problem is. Can't see anything to do with parameters here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not able to code for  Zw = {(s,d) Є NXN|Zsdw = 1}: indices for disrupted flows in at iteration (w).

Comment: Like @TimChippingtonDerrick I still cannot understand exactly what's the problem. Are you having problems figuring it out how to get the extreme points or extreme rays for the generating Bender's cuts?